# Probability of two persons to sit next to each other in a plane

Tags: probability, problem-solving, factorial

Two weeks ago I came up with the following probability problem (maybe a similar one already exists):

A plane has $60$ seats, disposed by groups of $3$ seats, $2$ groups per row ($10$ rows):

$$
\text{cockpit}
\\
S_{1}S_{2}S_{3}\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }S_{4}S_{5}S_{6}
\\
S_{7}S_{8}S_{9}\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }S_{10}S_{11}S_{12}
\\
...
\\
S_{55}S_{56}S_{57}\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }S_{58}S_{59}S_{60}
\\
\text{tail of the plane}
$$

All seats were booked and seats are assigned randomly to each person with an equal probability.

What is the probability that person $p_{1}$ and person $p_{2}$ will sit next to each other?

My solution to the problem was the following:

There are $60!$ possible outcomes, let $p_{n}$ be a person sitting on a seat:

$\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } 1)\text{ Starting from seat number 1: } p_{1}p_{2}p_{3} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{4}p_{5}p_{6} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } ... \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{58}p_{59}p_{60}\text{ (until seat number 60)}$

$\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } 2)\text{ Starting from seat number 1: } \text{ } p_{1}p_{3}p_{2} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{4}p_{5}p_{6} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } ... \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{58}p_{59}p_{60} \text{ (until seat number 60)}$

$\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } ...$

$\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } 60!)\text{ Starting from seat number 1: }\text{ } p_{60}p_{59}p_{58} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{57}p_{56}p_{55} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } ... \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{3}p_{2}p_{1}\text{ (until seat number 60)}$

Then the outcomes where the event $p_{1}\text{ sits next to }p_{2}$ occurs are the following (note that seats are grouped by 3):

$\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ }1) \text{ } \color{red}{p_{1}p_{2}}p_{3} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{4}p_{5}p_{6} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } ... \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{58}p_{59}p_{60}$

$\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ }2) \text{ } \color{red}{p_{2}p_{1}}p_{3} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{4}p_{5}p_{6} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } ... \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{58}p_{59}p_{60}$

$\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ }3) \text{ } p_{3}\color{red}{p_{1}p_{2}} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{4}p_{5}p_{6} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } ... \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{58}p_{59}p_{60}$

$\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ }4) \text{ } p_{3}\color{red}{p_{2}p_{1}} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{4}p_{5}p_{6} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } ... \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{58}p_{59}p_{60}$

$\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ }5) \text{ } p_{3}p_{4}p_{5} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } \color{red}{p_{1}p_{2}}p_{6} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } ... \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{58}p_{59}p_{60}$

$\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ }6) \text{ } p_{3}p_{4}p_{5} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } \color{red}{p_{2}p_{1}}p_{6} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } ... \text{ }\text{ }\text{ } p_{58}p_{59}p_{60}$

$\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ }...$

Since for each group of 3 seats there are 4 possible cases when $p1$ and $p2$ sit next to each other, e.g.:

$\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \color{red}{p_{1}p_{2}}p_{3}$

$\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \color{red}{p_{2}p_{1}}p_{3}$

$\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } p_{3}\color{red}{p_{1}p_{2}}$

$\text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } p_{3}\color{red}{p_{2}p_{1}}$

and since there are $20$ groups of seats in the plane, each group with $3$ seats, I would say that the outcomes where $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ sit next to each other are $20 \cdot 4 \cdot (58!) = 80 \cdot 58!$ (20 groups times the 4 possible cases per group for which the statement $p_{1} \text{ sits next to } p_{2}$ holds true times the number of permutations of the remaining $60 - 2 = 58$ persons).

Therefore my answer would be:

$P(p_{1} \text{ sits next to } p_{2}) = \frac{\frac{60}{3}\cdot 4 \cdot 58!}{60!} = \frac{20 \cdot 4 \cdot (58!)}{60!} = \frac{20 \cdot 4 \cdot (58!)}{60 \cdot 59 \cdot (58!)} = \frac{80}{60 \cdot 59} = 0.02259887005 = 2.259887005\text{%}$

Are my reasoning and solution correct?

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Comment: You could simplify the computation by only considering the two people in question (and ignoring the other 58) and by looking at the (unordered) combination of two seats where they sit. The denominator is then $60*59/2 possible pairs of seats and the numerator is 40 (2 pairs of adjacent seats in each of the 20 half-rows of 3 seats).

Comment: Why $60*59/2$ in the denominator, I mean what is the reasoning leading to it? Thank you

Comment: There are $60$ ways to pick the seat of person 1 and $59$ ways to pick the seat of person 2.  However, what we care about is whether they sit in adjacent seats.  Thus, if they switch seats, it will not affect whether or not they sit next to each other.  Hence, we can divide $60 \cdot 59$ by $2$ to count the pairs of seats they occupy.

Comment: That makes sense now, I am sorry guys but I usually always need an explanation to understand a topic, thank you for having clarified!